# Jquery. Параметр функции в зависимости от условия

Tags: jquery, параметры

Можно ли менять значение параметра функции в зависимости от условия, написанного внутри этой же функции и параметре? :)

Если более подробно то имею ввиду вот это:

Есть некая функция (инициализирует jquery плагин при загрузке страницы):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.zoom').elevateZoom({
        responsive: true,
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        scrollZoom: false,
        borderSize: 0,
        tintColour: '#ff9933'
    });
});
```

Среди параметров есть такой: `scrollZoom` - ему можно указать значение `true` или `false`.

Долгие часы ищу способ сделать следующее:
если размер окна браузера меньше или равно 991px - задать значение `false`,
а если больше - задать значение `true`.

(В идеале бы конечно было отслеживать изменение размера окна и при его изменении задавать нужное значение, перезапуская каким-то образом функцию если пользователь меняет размер окошка браузера, но это помоему невозможно).

Пробовал вот так:

```js
zoom: function() 
{
    if ($(window).width() <= '991') {
     return 'false';
    } else {
     return 'true';
    }
}
```

но это не работает. Можно ли провернуть это каким-то образом? :(

ps
если важно - речь об этом плагине http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if ($(window).width() <= '991') {
        setScrollZoom = false;
    } else {
        setScrollZoom = true;
    }
    $('.zoom').elevateZoom({
        responsive: true,
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        scrollZoom: setScrollZoom,
        borderSize: 0,
        tintColour: '#ff9933'
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно. А насчет этого я прав - "(В идеале бы конечно было ЕЩЁ и отслеживать изменение размера окна и при его изменении задавать нужное значение, перезапуская каким-то образом функцию если пользователь меняет размер окошка браузера, но это помоему невозможно)." ?

Comment: Это больше вопрос к разработчикам плагина  `elevateZoom`. Ничто Вам не мешает сделать пересчет внутри `$( window ).resize(function() { });`. Однако позволит Вам этот плагин?...